# How to make zoom function within a div tag in phonegap

Tags: android, iphone, cordova, zooming

I want to know how to make zoom function with phonegap. Recently I tried zoom function with [cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/zoom/](http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/zoom/).
It works on samsung galaxy s4, but does't work on tablet and it's not responsive.
Anybody please recommend me which library is good for zoom.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You had the right idea but your link is to v4 of iScroll. Get the latest version here - http://iscrolljs.com/ - and make sure you **look at the examples which include zooming**.

Some iScroll libraries are just for scrolling and do not zoom!

I used only the `iscroll-zoom.js` file in my Phonegap app. Here's my code:

```
    <script src="iscroll-zoom.js"></script>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="scroller">
            <img src="whatever" width="1150" height="1150" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    var myScroll;
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
    setTimeout(function () {
        myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', {
            zoom: true,
            scrollX: true,
            scrollY: true,
            mouseWheel: true,
            wheelAction: 'zoom'
        });
    }, 100);
</script>
```

Most of the JS needs to be within `onDeviceReady`.

This worked in Android (Nexus 7) and iOS (iPhone5).